# How to fix "comparing userform textbox with cellvalue" code

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding a record in next row with a sr.no and other data. When I enter a number in userform textbox, it must check if it is not duplicating. The numbers are in serial order

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Worksheet

    Set y = Sheets("Data")
    x = y.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If CInt(TextBox1.Value) <= CInt((Sheets("Data").Range
    .Cells(x, "A").Value)) 
    Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate serial no. found. Increase it"
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: From a user friendliness point of view, you shouldn't at all ask the user to insert the serial number but just get the next one and provide it in read-only mode into the user form.

Comment: Also, note you're in a change event and you're popping up a MsgBox everytime the text in the box is smaller or equal than the last Sr. No. in your list. This means that when you will have 1,000 records and your user will want to type 1,001, they will have: "type 1 -> msgbox", "type 10" -> msgbox", "type 100 -> msgbox", "type 1,001 -> finally ok". Your users would hate you for that :)

Comment: And to complete this small code review via comments, please also note you're not handling any `IsNumeric()` before applying `CInt(TextBox1.Value)`. This means that if the user types a letter in it, your code would crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted might pretty much working already, but I would go for a different approach.

A **serial number** is a value that the system should compute, not the user should insert. My suggestion would hence be to get the next serial number with a function:

```
Private Function getNextSerial() As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Worksheet

    Set y = Sheets("Data")
    x = y.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    getNextSerial = y.Cells(x, "A").Value + 1 
End Function
```

... and to set it directly in your `TextBox1` when you initialize the form. For example, assuming your form is called `MyUserForm`, in the `Initialize()` event of this form you should put something like this:

```
Me.TextBox1.Text = getNextSerial() '<-- write next serial
Me.TextBox1.Locked = True '<-- forbid writing
```

If you really wanna go for the approach where the user types in the serial number, then you can still use the function `getNextSerial()` and write:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text <= getNextSerial() Then
```

... however, please note that you're doing this in a `TextBox.Change` event. This means that if the user wants to type 1001 as a value, with your current code they would have:

- Typing "1" --> `MsgBox` pops-up
- Continuing with "10" --> `MsgBox` popping up again
- Continuing with "100" --> `MsgBox` popping up again!
- End typing "1001" --> Finally!

... which would cause a high sense of hate from the users towards the system :)

Comment: Sorry didn't know you were posting an asnwer :)

Comment: One suggestion... `Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False` can be `Me.TextBox1.Locked= True`. to disable editing and yet look pretty much alive :P

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MatteoNNZ. No need to ask the user for the S.No. As it is how would the user know which one is the currect user number?

I recommend 2 Options

[A] **Auto insert S.No:** From your image, row number will always be (Lastrow - 5) So if you are going to fill Row 9 then your S.No will be `9-5=4`. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Insert Sno
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = lRow - 5
    End With
End Sub
```

[B] **Autopopulate S.No in the form**: Find the last row and subtract 5 from it and then show it in the userform. Keep the textbox `locked`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     '~~> Insert Sno
     TextBox1.Text = lRow - 5
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't know either until 5 minutes ago :) Going to delete mine, you came first :)